# The value of the property 'WebForm_AutoFocus' is null or undefined, not a Function object

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

We have an application which uses a link, on click of that link it opens a jQuery popup window and focus on one text box of popup window. We are facing some issue while opening the pop up window, the steps in which the issue comes while opening are -

1. Initially Pop up jQuery dialog workes fine and we are able to select a value and go ahead to setup the account.
2. Open another portal/application within same browser and do some work and close that portal.
3. Then Again if i go to main portal and clicks on the **link** for account setup which should open the dialog box is throwing an error:

> The value of the property 'WebForm_AutoFocus' is null or undefined,
>   not a Function object

I captured this error by using the browser's developer tools.

In some post I have read that this may be because of- jQuery is not loading properly, but in developer tools I am able to see jquery script.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue. In the browser's console it was saying like `WebForm_AutoFocus` is null or not defined. Iit seems like it is due to `webresource.axd` issue.

I referred [channel9.msdn.com - .NET Framework 1.1 Service Pack 1 problem](http://channel9.msdn.com/forums/TechOff/20959-NET-Framework-11-Service-Pack-1-problem/#Page=2) . And I replaced the `ASPNET_CLIENT` folder in my website’s virtual directory. [I copied it from a machine where the functionality is working fine. Source Location - "C:\Inetpub\wwwroot"] .Restarted IIS.

The issue seems to be resolved now; however I am not sure about the root cause. The only difference in my server (when compared with my colleagues system) is that I have `Ajax 1.0` installed.

**Compression**

Another post that says about `compression` is [Client-side functionality (DefaultFocus, DefaultButton, etc.) not working](http://forums.asp.net/t/1102331.aspx?Client+side+functionality+DefaultFocus+DefaultButton+etc+not+working)